# How to call generic function in Go, by passing a Type from reflection

Tags: go

I have a Go app that can receive different JSON responses for the same API, so I am trying to write a custom unmarshaller, that will try to handle each possible JSON response until it finds the correct one.

To do this, I've created a generic function that unmarshalls the JSON, and I want to call it using a type that I get from reflection.

For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type JSONHandler struct{}

func (handler *JSONHandler) Unmarshal(data []byte) error {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(*handler)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldType := t.Field(i)

        fmt.Printf("Trying to unmarshal: %s\n", fieldType.Name)
        result, err := unmarshal[fieldType](data) // fieldType (variable of type reflect.StructField) is not a typecompiler (NotAType)

        if err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("result: %s\n", result)
            break
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func unmarshal[T interface{}](data []byte) (*T, error) {
    obj := new(T)

    reader := bytes.NewReader(data)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(reader)
    decoder.DisallowUnknownFields()

    err := decoder.Decode(obj)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return obj, nil
}

type User struct {
    Username *string `json:"username,omitempty"`
    Password *string `json:"password,omitempty"`
}

type UserError struct {
    Error *string `json:"error,omitempty"`
    Code  *int    `json:"code,omitempty"`
}

type UserOrError struct {
    User      *User
    UserError *UserError
    JSONHandler
}

var userJson = `{ "username": "john@email.com", "password": "password" }`

func main() {
    user := new(UserOrError)
    result := user.Unmarshal([]byte(userJson)) // { User: something, UserError: nil }
}
```

However, the Go compiler gives me this error: `fieldType (variable of type reflect.StructField) is not a typecompiler (NotAType)`.

Is there a way to pass the reflection parameter to the generic function?

Comment: No. Reflection is about runtime type information. Generics is about compile time type information. That said, there are ways of doing what you want. One would be to give up writing a custom `unmarshal` function, and use plain old `json.Unmarshal` with a custom unmarshaler if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is outside the domain of Go's generic feature.

Use [reflect.New](https://godoc.org/reflect#New) to create a value given the reflect.Type for that value.

Go does not have inheritance.  The Unmarshal method in the question operates on a type with no fields.  Fix by passing the "handler" to a plain function.

```
// Unmarshal unmarshals data to each field type in handler
// and returns the first successful result. The handler argument
// must be a pointer to a struct.
func Unmarshal(handler any, data []byte) (any, error) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(handler).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldType := t.Field(i)
        v := reflect.New(fieldType.Type)
        decoder := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(data))
        decoder.DisallowUnknownFields()
        err := decoder.Decode(v.Interface())
        if err == nil {
            return v.Elem().Interface(), err
        }
    }
    return nil, errors.New("no matching type")
}
```

Use the Marshal function like this:

```
type UserOrError struct {
    User      *User
    UserError *UserError
}

var userJson = `{ "username": "john@email.com", "password": "password" }`

result, err := Unmarshal(&UserOrError{}, []byte(userJson)) // { User: something, UserError: nil }
fmt.Printf("err=%v, result=%#v\n", err, result)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/mMnV6AWiuS9